# What has more randomness?

Tags: entropy

Four particles in a line or along a square, which has higher entropy?

Just for a minute question.

×  ×  ×  ×

×    ×

×    ×

Comment: What are your thought? Please show some effort.

Comment: @Nephente I have no thought . You can just answer in a word. I would remove question immediately.

Comment: Imagine a 2x4 grid and you randomly scatter 4 points. What is the probability of creating a straight line, and of creating a square?

Comment: (Or put more simply, how many different ways are there of creating a straight line, and of creating a square?)

Comment: @lemon Why a 2× 4 grid?

Comment: That's the smallest grid that supports both a straight line as well as a square. If you want to imagine an even bigger grid then you can but that just complicates things (and you will come to the same conclusion anyway).

Comment: @lemon Thanks I got it. Square has more randomness.

Comment: @lemon gure has a point.

Comment: Our disagreement is because we have interpreted the question differently. I have considered your x's to be the fundamental components of your system; that they are free to move around independently of each other, whereas @gure has regarded the line and the square each as a single, rigid unit. So which interpretation had you intended?

Comment: @lemon Yours. They were free.

Comment: Then your conclusion is correct: the square has higher entropy. If they're rigid, like gure had assumed, then those constraints implicitly reduce the configuration space for the square more so than for the line.

Comment: Why a down vote? Please flag question if not appropriate, since I cannot delete it after an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that both have the same entropy if the positions are fixed.

If the line and rectangular are free however, this adds a two fold symmetry to the line (just flipping it) but a four-fold rotation plus a two-fold flipping symmetry to the square. Thus in this case the square has less distinct configurations.